# Jquery click event dont fire

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, signalr

Im using jquery and signalR to make a little chat for a school project.

When a user writes something in the chat and post it runs the `AddMessage` script

```
function AddMessage(userName, message) {
    $('#divChatWindow').append('<div class="message"><span class="userName">' + userName + '</span>: ' + message + '</div><button class="Remove">x</button>');

    var height = $('#divChatWindow')[0].scrollHeight;
        $('#divChatWindow').scrollTop(height);
    }
}
```

Im trying to make click event on `<button class="Remove">x</button>` but no matter what i try it cant make it fire the click event.

```
$('body').on('click', '.Remove', function () {
    alert("FIRE");
});
```

Anyone have an idea what to do inorder to fix this?

Ther is no error messages in my console window if i hit F12

Answer (score 1):

You need to wrap it in

```
$(document).ready(function(){

});
```

So:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $('body').on('click', '.Remove', function () {
                alert("FIRE");
        });

});
```

Comment: Or delegate it to `document` level